# эффект печатной машинки когда текст появляется на сцене не сразу

Tags: ui, unity3d

как сделать так чтобы скрипт запускался в тот момент когда ui text будет SetActive = true
и сбрасывался когда SetActive = false ?

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Text;
using System;

public class UITextTypeWriter: MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text text;
    public bool playOnAwake = true;
    public float delayToStart;
    public float delayBetweenChars = 0.125f;
    public float delayAfterPunctuation = 0.5f;

    private string story;
    private float originDelayBetweenChars;
    private bool lastCharPunctuation = false;
    private char charComma;
    private char charPeriod;

    void Awake()
    {
        text = GetComponent<Text>();
        originDelayBetweenChars = delayBetweenChars;

        charComma = Convert.ToChar(44);
        charPeriod = Convert.ToChar(46);

        if (playOnAwake)
        {
            ChangeText(text.text, delayToStart);
        }
     }


    public void ChangeText(string textContent, float delayBetweenChars = 0f)
    {
        StopCoroutine(PlayText()); 
        story = textContent;
        text.text = ""; 
        Invoke("Start_PlayText", delayBetweenChars); 
    }

    void Start_PlayText()
    {
        StartCoroutine(PlayText());
    }

    IEnumerator PlayText()
    {

        foreach (char c in story)
        {
            delayBetweenChars = originDelayBetweenChars;

            if (lastCharPunctuation) 
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayBetweenChars = delayAfterPunctuation);
                lastCharPunctuation = false;
            }
         
            if (c == charComma || c == charPeriod)
            {
                lastCharPunctuation = true;
            }

            text.text += c;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayBetweenChars);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnEnable()` срабатывает при `SetActive(true)` и сразу после `Awake()`, если активен.

`OnDisable()` срабатывает при `SetActive(false)` и перед уничтожением, как `OnDestroy()`.

`StopCoroutine` так не работает.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[DisallowMultipleComponent]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Text))]

public class UITextTypeWriter : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string _content;
    [Space]
    [SerializeField] private float _startDelay = 0f;
    [SerializeField] private float _delayBetweenChars = 0.125f;
    [SerializeField] private float _delayAfterPunctuation = 0.5f;
    
    private IEnumerator _corutine;

    private void OnEnable ()
    {
        Play();
    }

    private void OnDisable ()
    {
        Stop();
    }

    public void PlayContent (string content, Action onFinish = null)
    {
        _content = content;
        Play(onFinish);
    }

    private void Play (Action onFinish = null)
    {
        Stop();
        _corutine = PlayCorutine(onFinish);
        StartCoroutine(_corutine);
    }

    private void Stop ()
    {
        if (_corutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(_corutine);
        _corutine = null;
    }

    private IEnumerator PlayCorutine (Action onFinish = null)
    {
        if (_startDelay > 0)
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(_startDelay);
        char[] Punctuations = { 
            Convert.ToChar(44), 
            Convert.ToChar(46) 
        };
        Text Text = GetComponent<Text>();
        Text.text = "";
        int Index = -1;
        char CurrentChar = '\0';
        float Timer = 0;
        float TargetTime = 0;
        while (Index < _content.Length)
        {
            Timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (Timer >= TargetTime)
            {
                Timer -= TargetTime;
                Text.text += CurrentChar;
                Index++;
                if (Index < _content.Length)
                {
                    CurrentChar = _content[Index];
                    bool Punctuation = Array.Exists(Punctuations, p => p == CurrentChar);
                    TargetTime = Punctuation ? _delayAfterPunctuation : _delayBetweenChars;
                }
            }
            yield return null;
        }
        onFinish?.Invoke();
        _corutine = null;
    }
}
```